# Convert a MemberIterator to Value

Tags: c++, rapidjson

In C++ you can easily get the underlying value from the iterator. ie:

```
std::vector<int> numbers = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5 };

for (std::vector<int>::iterator it = numbers.begin(); it != numbers.end(); ++it) {
    int i = *it;
    std::cout << "i = " << i << std::endl;
}
```

However using rapidjson I am having trouble in getting the underlying value from ConstMemberIterator:

```
rapidjson::Value* values;
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator it = values->MemberBegin(); it != values->MemberEnd(); ++it) {
    rapidjson::Value v = *it; // ERROR!
}
```

> error: conversion from ‘rapidjson::GenericMemberIterator<true, rapidjson::UTF8<>, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocatorrapidjson::CrtAllocator >::ValueType {aka const rapidjson::GenericMemberrapidjson::UTF8<, rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocatorrapidjson::CrtAllocator >}’ to non-scalar type ‘rapidjson::Value {aka rapidjson::GenericValuerapidjson::UTF8< >}’ requested
> rapidjson::Value v = *it;

How do I get the underlying value so I can do further operations on it?

The only way I have found is to convert the value to a string and then reparse the string as a document and go in via document[it->name.GetString()] since there also seemingly no way to convert a value to a document.

Comment: `MemberBegin` is for json values that are objects. If object then you get the value using `it->value`;

Answer (score 2):

If you're using C++11, you could try and use `auto`...

```cpp
rapidjson::Value* values;
for (rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator it = values->MemberBegin(); it != values->MemberEnd(); ++it) {
    auto v = *it;
}
```

Comment: This give error: ```‘rapidjson::GenericMember<Encoding, Allocator>::GenericMember(const rapidjson::GenericMember<Encoding, Allocator>&) [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>]’ is private within this context```

Comment: does this `auto v = it->value;` make any difference?

Comment: No.  ```error: ‘rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>::GenericValue(const rapidjson::GenericValue<Encoding, Allocator>&) [with Encoding = rapidjson::UTF8<>; Allocator = rapidjson::MemoryPoolAllocator<rapidjson::CrtAllocator>]’ is private within this context```

Comment: I just realised that it might have something to do with the way you declared your array...  
The `rapidjson::Value` type has the public `ConstValueIterator` attribute. But using this will not give you an _iterator on the whole array_, because you've declare your array using a pointer.  Could you try to change the inital declaration for something like `std::vector<rapidjson::Value> values;` ?

Comment: The initial way I receive the json is simply as: `bool ::getValues(rapidjson::Value * values) const;`  Unfortunately there is not a lot I can do about the function name as it is used in other parts of the code. My personal feeling it should be an array but it isn't.

Comment: If you were to try to change the `rapidjson::Value::ConstMemberIterator it = values->MemberBegin();` with `rapidjson::Value::MemberIterator it = values->MembreBegin();` ...
If that doesn't work, tt'd be useful if we could have a little info on what the `values` actually contains...
What if you tried to `std::cout` things like `values->MemberCount()`, `values->MemberCapacity` and `values->hasMember()`?